# Структура объектов

Tags: python

Привет всем!
у меня вопрос по структуре объектов:

```
>>> L = ['abc', [(1, 2), ([3], 4)], 5]
```

Почему именно такой порядок: в первом ряде 0, 1, 2 а во втором ряду и ниже 0 начинается не с первого бокса (abc)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое, все теперь ясно

Comment: если опубликован ответ, который вам помог решить проблему, то [вы можете его принять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), чтобы было ясно, что вопрос решён (комментарии можно не оставлять)

Answer (score 1):

На первом уровне (в самом "внешнем" списке) хранятся "ссылки" на 3 объекта: `'abc'`, `[(1, 2), ([3], 4)]`, `5`. Эти ссылки и отображены с помощью линий. Числа в квадратных скобках на диаграмме как бы символизируют индексы (номера элементов) внутри списков или кортежей.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему где-то выбраны списки, а где-то кортежи. Разве на диаграмме как-то изображено отличие между ними?

Comment: @NickVolynkin под диаграммой исходная структура написана.

Comment: Да, я увидел её. Просто не понимаю, почему там `([3], 4)`, а не `[(3,), 4]`, например.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, структура данных (код под диаграммой) как бы первична, а диаграмма просто демонстрирует внутренние связи. Если наоборот идти от диаграммы, то действительно не понять списки или кортежи используются.